# Attempted to load class from namespace

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I have required Goutte on the local machine in reason that hosting server has a low memory for using composer.

```
composer require fabpot/goutte
```

And copy files to servers vendor

I trying to use this `**$client = new \Goutte\Client();**` but
There is error

> Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "Goutte"

What am I missing?
I have double checked that files are in the right folder.
Tried to clear cache but still the same error.

Comment: You can't just upload the library files to the servers vendor. You need to upload the autoload-files as well. That's were composer stores the namespace => folder-mapping.

Comment: I missed that. I will try now this :)

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. You can write answer to mark it as helpful :)

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require a library, it doesn't just download the files, it also adds any namespaces registered in the library's composer.json-file to the main autoloader.

So if you just upload the library files to the servers vendor, composer won't know where to look for that library's namespace.

All you need to do is to upload composers autoload-files as well.

#### Note

If the library installs any dependencies, you will need to upload those as well. Basically, upload the complete `vendor`-folder and you should be good to go.